# Есть задание.(Java) Создать файл данных, компонентами которого являются целые числа. Заменить в этом файле все четные числа на 0

Tags: java

Подскажите , как это можно сделать.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   int[] num = new int[4];
    try {
       Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\file.txt"));
       System.out.println("Вывод, с учетом замены целых четных чисел на '0':" );
       for(int i = 0;i < 4; i++){
       num[i] = in.nextInt();
       System.out.println(num[i]);
       }
       in.close();

   }
   catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {
       ex.printStackTrace();
   }
   catch(NoSuchElementException ex){
       System.out.println("Input File is incorrect...");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, в вашем задании не сказано, в каком формате нужно записывать (и потом читать) файл с числами и сколько чисел должно быть. Поэтому логичным кажется рассмотреть какой-то общий случай. Тогда никакого смысла использовать массив нет -- ведь размер заранее неизвестен (да и вообще -- зачем нам массив? Просто читаем из файла числа и тут же записываем либо само прочитанное число, если оно нечетное, либо 0, если число четное).

Дальше, `Scanner` обладает замечательной способностью сообщать, есть ли у него еще данные, так что нет нужды использовать `for`, можно использовать `while` -- `пока (естьЕщеДанные) { прочитать; обработать; }`

Потом, начиная с `Java 7` (а вы вряд ли используете более старую) есть конструкция, которая позволяет намного изящнее работать с файлами -- не надо писать многоэтажных `try ... catch ... finally` с вложениями, можно просто использовать то, что называется `try with resources`, а именно  написать `try (описать и открыть файл) { работать с файлом }` и всё - файл будет закрыт автоматически.

И еще одно -- в задании сказано "создать файл", а у вас он не создается -- вы почему-то предполагаете, что он уже должен существовать.

Таким образом, если не использовать новые возможности `Java 8` (которых вы, похоже, еще не изучали), а решить задачу примерно в таком стиле, как вы пытались (со сканерами и т. п.), то получается примерно такой код:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Запишем файл со случайными целыми числами 
        try ( PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("file.txt")); ) {
            int count = (int)((Math.random() + 0.5) * 1000); // 500 to 1500 numbers
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                out.print((int)( (Math.random() - 0.5) * 2.0 * Integer.MAX_VALUE) + " ");
                if (i % 10 == 0)    // 10 numbers per line
                    out.println();
            }
        } catch (IOException x) { System.out.println("IO error: " + x); }

        // Теперь прочитаем этот файл и перепишем в новый,
        // заменив чётные числа нулями  
        try (Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("file.txt")); // "try с ресурсами"
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("out_file.txt"));) {
            System.out.println("Вывод, с учетом замены целых четных чисел на '0':");
            while (in.hasNextLine()) {
                Scanner line = new Scanner(in.nextLine()); // Одна строка файла
                while (line.hasNextInt()) {             // Разберем ее на числа
                    int data = line.nextInt();          // Очередное число 
                    if (data % 2 == 0) {                // Если чётное 
                        System.out.format("%d -> 0, ", data); // Чтоб было видно, что делается
                        data = 0;                       // Заменим его нулём 
                    } else
                        System.out.print(data + ", ");  // Чтоб было видно, что делается
                    out.print(data + ", ");
                }
                line.close();                   // Не забывать, чтобы не было утечек
                out.println();                  // Строка закончена -- перенос строки в вых. файл 
                System.out.println();           // и на экране
            }
        } catch (IOException x) { System.out.println("IO error: " + x); }
        // И всё. Файлы закрыты 
    } // main
```

Comment: спасибо огромное. Спасибо. Не ожидал. Спасибо огромное,

Answer (score 1):

При условии что в файле числа хранятся в виде 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ... (вариант далёк от идеала...)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    File file = new File("C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\file.txt");

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file)))) {

        String[] words = br.readLine().split(" ");

        for (String number : words) {
            if (Integer.valueOf(number)%2 == 0) {
                sb.append(0 + " ");
            } else {
                sb.append(number).append(" ");
            }
        }

        FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file);
        fileWriter.write(sb.toString());
        fileWriter.close();


    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }        
}
```

Comment: то есть, только файл из одной строки, в которой числа разделены пробелами. И вы забыли закрыть выходной файл.

Comment: @m.vokhm Спасибо, исправил код.